# Seam ajax file upload

Tags: ajax, asyncfileupload, seam2

I have looked into several components for Ajax file uploads and am aware that RichFaces has one, but I'm looking for something simpler. It should be rendered similar to a basic input of type file. I guess if I could figure out how to style the RichFaces one that would be fine, but it would take a ton of tweaking to get it to look basic.

Basically, I only want to do one file at a time on a modal panel, do I don't want to kill the conversation by submitting the form. I have looked at some jQuery stuff, but don't know how to wire it to the back end. Most examples use PHP. It seems to me that I am going to have to write a servlet to handle the upload. Is this correct, or is there something easier I'm overlooking that would allow me just to bind to a Seam backing entity?